# How to autosize the editText dynamically?

Tags: android

How to autoSize editText dynamically that when user input some data then it goes from some max size to min size of text in android like the typemode in instagram? I want to make editText working like this

[enter link description here](https://miro.medium.com/max/764/1*Chw3Adea66Me49A2wPGR-g.gif)

Answer (score 1):

You can use these attributes in your layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/your_edit_text"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:maxLines="1"
        app:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
        app:autoSizeMinTextSize="12sp"
        app:autoSizeMaxTextSize="25sp"
        app:autoSizeStepGranularity="2sp"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

The attribute `app:autoSizeTextType` can be set to `uniform` or `none`,

The attribute `app:autoSizeMinTextSize` is the minimum dimension,

The attribute `app:autoSizeMaxTextSize` is the maximum dimension,

The attribute `app:autoSizeStepGranularity` is the increment of the scaling.

Comment: This actually deletes the text that inside the edittext after the line is full, good answer tho so +1 from me.

Comment: I want to do something like this   https://miro.medium.com/max/764/1*Chw3Adea66Me49A2wPGR-g.gif

Answer (score 0):

You can use [AutoFitEditText](https://github.com/ViksaaSkool/AutoFitEditText) libray, or [android-autofittextview](https://github.com/grantland/android-autofittextview) library.